# intellij idea system wide VCS ignored files

Tags: version-control, ide, intellij-idea

I'm using intellij idea 12 on Ubuntu 13.04 with the ruby and git plugin, is there anyway to make IDE use the `.gitignore` file OR a way to make all new rails project have specific "ignore files" specified in the setting?

Currently I end up having to add the ignored files one by one in every new rails project.
I tried reading up on the documentation but it said it was possible to make system-wide ignored files setting but didn't specify how.

Comment: You want don't want to see the files from .gitignore in the IDE?

Comment: I would prefer that Intellij used the .gitignore file for making the git plugin ignore some files, that or allow me to make system wide ignored files list for all new projects.

Comment: What program to you want to ignore those files in .gitignore? Git or Intellij? Git ignores files in .gitignore anyway and Intellij can only ignore whole folders (as far as I know).

Comment: I found out how to ignore files folders and wildcards in intellij, but i have to do it each time for all new projects, it gets rediois. Looking for some way to make all new rails projects ignore the commonly ignored files without manually adding that setting to each project.

Comment: As far as I know it is project specific; you can send a feedback to JetBrains and request a new feature. They are very responsive.